# phpmyadmin Lock Down

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a client that wants to use myphpadmin to manage his mysql database 5.x on my server. I found this article on how to hide databases from myphpadmin but I don't like this because if I don't specify the databases to hide then every time I add a new database it because available to the client through myphpadmin.

Article: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/hide-databases-phpmyadmin/

Command to hide a database in the myphpadmin config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'hidedb1|hidedb2|etc...';
```

I also created a separate username and password in mysql to.

Is there a way to reverse this so I can tell myphpadmin what database to only show for this login?

Thanks,

Frank G.